# Security: ASp.NET Identity HTTPOnly Cookie with SSL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, httpcookie

This is a general question as I am used to User object being stored in the session and I am learning the new identity framework.

I see a lot of talk about sending down "Claims" as apart of the cookie.  So that way you don't have to re-look up the user information Meaning such things as name, email or even permissions are apart of the claims area in the cookie that is saved.

Everything I have studied on this, says httpOnly over SSL is very safe in terms of being hacked.  I am hesitant to send anything but a userid to identify the user and then look up the rest in the DB to ensure at least if the user is hacked the permissions are not hacked.  Am I being over cautious?

I also see people setting cookies to expire in 7 days or 1 day ect...In respects to that and you are sending down the permissions/roles in the claims area.  What happens if they change on the server.  Basically it seems that the user would need to log in and log out in order for the new permissions to take place.  Was wondering is that the norm expectation with software UI standards?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts :)

Angela

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my ignorance, but i've not come across a piece of software where the claims would be sent in cookies. Typically, the problem with cookies is the possibility of `XSS` (Cross-site scripting) attacks because browsers are written to always send them.

What people tend to do these days is use a federated authentication mechanism these days, where the Identity Provider (login page) and the Service Provider (the app code) are not necessarily the same app, and are not always directly connected. This means that the user's data that you could lookup in the db exists only in IdP and SP has to deal with whatever the IdP provided.

This is why each bit of information is sent in a 'claim'. This means that the IdP claims that the username is john.smith, but SP may not have any means of checking this.

To make it work, the IdP and SP should have established some form of trust, typically in the form of pre shared signing keys which allows the IdP to sign the token (SAML envelope or JWT, for example) and the SP to verify the signature to be able to check that the token has not been tampered with.

Typically, this token is never used as a cookie; instead it is added to an `Authorization` header, normally using `Bearer` scheme.

Also, as a side note - when you say you're familiar with using sessions, you have to understand that a session tracker is also a cookie (in ASP.NET). The server has information about a user stored in the app pool's memory cache and the browser keeps sending the cookie saying 'here i am'. So security wise there is comparable level between simply using cookies or using cookies + session. Of course one could argue that a cookie could leak information, but an app could always tokenize the data or encrypt the whole cookie negating this argument.

Comment: @zaitman, thanks for taking the time :) I researched tokens and the authorization Header and found the same thing.  Advocating adding the user permissions into the "payload" so the user does not have to be reloaded up every request. As far as Cookies versus the Authorization header.  From my understanding is the Authorization header can be hacked with XSS  because it can be read via client side which is why they are encrypting it and providing a signature for verification it is real.  You can do _request.getResponseHeader(name).  The cookie cannot be read when using HTTPOnly and SSL.

Comment: @Angela While it is definitely a guideline to disallow such cookies to be read for the client, this specific implementation detail is left to the discretion of the client writers. E.g. in iOS WebView you can easily access those cookies from the native code.

Tokens are also useful as they can be universally used for cases when non-browser related interaction is required, e.g. for code flow or refresh token flow. They are definitely not 'better' in any way and not really more secure, they just provide additional mechanisms and primary benefit is to allow user to login with external accounts.

Comment: Is the norm/standard to pass down permissions into either tokens or cookies? On the net people are advocating with Tokens to pass the user data through so you don't have to hit the database again an subsequent calls.  I see the same thing with cookies.  Maybe I am an old timer but I would think if it got hacked I certainly wouldn't want to open up the permissions to be mucked with.  Maybe they get the user but at least they could not muck with the permissions.  Thus forcing a DB call every time back to the server to grab the permission before performing an action for that person.

Comment: @Angela If your design is secure enough, then yes you could put permissions into tokens. The main reason it is done, however, is NOT so you don't have to 'hit the database' but rather because the IdP database doesn't actually exist within your app. And of course if you're using tokens they're always signed (at least) and you can make them encrypted also resulting in user having no visibility over those values.